# PHP Laravel if( !empty()) running code when empty

Tags: php

I have a code that is supposed to run if an array is not empty but for some reason, it will still run even if it is empty. Here is what I have:

```
$fifteenDays = Carbon::today('America/Los_Angeles')->subDays(15);
$invoiceSent = Invoice::whereDate('invoiceDue', '<=',$fifteenDays)->where('isPaid', 0)->where('isPaying', 0)->get();

if (!empty($invoiceSent)) {
   //Run Code In here
}
```

This will run regardless of whether or not `$invoiceSent` is empty.

Comment: So what _is_ $invoiceSent? `var_dump($invoiceSent)` ahead of the `!empty` check should tell you want it actually is. If it's an object (such as a resultset) it won't be considered empty.

Comment: What's in $invoiceSent? empty() only satisfies a certain number of empty criteria, so if it's an array with a key that is empty it won't count. Read up on the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get()` method retuns a `Collection` which is a `Countable`.

This leads to `empty` actually being true, while `count()` would return 0. This is counter intuitive, but still a language specific feature.

Comment: Thank you, I changed to see if count was greater than 0 and it worked for me.